# Metric spaces "$\iff$" proof

Tags: proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(A, d_1)$ and be a metric. Suppose $d_2: A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined in this way:

For $a, b \in A$, $d_2(a, b) = \frac{d_1(a, b)}{1 + d_1(a, b)}$.

Show that $E \subset A$ is open with respect to $d_1 \iff E$ is open with respect to $d_2$.

My friend and I's attempt:

Assume $E$ is open inside $(A, d_2)$. Let $x \in E$. We need $B_{\rho}^{d_1} \subset E$ for some $\rho > 0$. We know that there is some $r > 0$ so that $B_{r}^{d_2} \subset E$.

Choose $\rho = ?$ so that $B_{\rho}^{d_1} \subset B_{r}^{d_2}$. (Not sure what $\rho$ to choose).

In essence, we need $d_1(x, a) < \rho \implies d_2(x, a) < r$.

Going the other way, assume $E$ is open with respect to $(A, d_1)$. Then $d_2(a, b) = \frac{d_1(a, b)}{1 + d_1(a, b)} \leq d_1(a, b) < r$.

Not sure how to proceed from here.

QED.

Is this proof correct so far? We are new to metric spaces and tried to connect the dots as much as possible. Can somebody fill in the holes in the proof and explain it? Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: First the easy direction. Let $E$ be open w.r.t. $d_2$. Let $x\in E$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r^{d_2}(x)\subset E$. Let us show that also $B_r^{d_1}(x)\subset E$. For this, let $y\in B_r^{d_1}(x)$. Then $d_1(x,y) < r$. What can we conclude for $d_2(x,y)$ and what follows from there?

Comment: @amsmath $B_{r}^{d_2} \subset B_{r}^{d_1} \subset E$?

Comment: I asked what we can conclude for $d_2(x,y)$.

Comment: @amsmath I'm not sure...

Comment: Well, then I'm sorry.

Comment: @Kraftsman: Given an $r>0$, you want a $\rho>0$ such that $0\le x<\rho$ implies that $\frac{x}{1+x}<r$. Clearly we may as well assume that $r<1$. Now $\frac{x}{1+x}<r$ if and only if $x<r+rx$, i.e., if and only if $x<\frac{r}{1-r}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So choose $\rho = \frac{r}{1-r}$?

Comment: @Kraftsman: Yes, though you should verify that it really does work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please check the updated solution? I have posted it as an answer. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced $a, b$ with $x, y$*

Proof.

Assume $E$ is open inside $(A, d_2)$. Then there is a $r > 0$ s.t. the open ball $B_2(x, r) = \{y \in A: d_2(x, y) < r\}$ is contained in $E$.

We need to show that for any $x \in E$, there is an $\rho > 0$ so that the open ball $B_1(x, \rho)  = \{y \in A: d_1(x, y) < \rho\}$ is contained in $E$.

Let $r < 1$ and set $\rho = \frac{r}{1 - r}$ then for $y \in B_1(x, \rho)$ we have

$$d_2(x, y) = \frac{d_1(x, y)}{1 + d_1(x, y)} < \frac{\rho}{1 + \rho} = r$$

So $y \in B_2(x, r)$ and so $B_1(x, \rho) \subset E$. Hence $E$ is open inside $(A, d_1)$.

The other way.

Assume $E$ is open inside $(A, d_1)$. Then there is a $\rho > 0$ s.t. the open ball $B_1(x, \rho) = \{y \in A: d_1(x, y) < \rho\}$ is contained in $E$.

We need to show that for any $x \in E$, there is an $r > 0$ so that the open ball $B_2(x, r)  = \{y \in A: d_2(x, y) < r\}$ is contained in $E$.

Set $r = \rho$ then for $y \in B_2(x, r)$ we have:

$$d_2(x, y) = \frac{d_1(x, y)}{1 + d_1(x, y)} \leq d_1(x, y) < \rho = r$$

So $y \in B_1(x, \rho)$ and $B_2(x, r) \subset E$. We may conclude $E$ is open inside $(A, d_2)$.

QED.